# Почему изменяется значение поля класса после его использования в цикле, который ни разу не исполнится?

Tags: java

вот есть фрагмент кода на языке программирования Java:

```
public class TestClass{
    static int x = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(x = 5;x<5;x++){}
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

..................................................
х=5.
// на выходе, после компиляции ,получается ответ х=5. Так вот объясните почему, я не понимаю.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что кроме как ТС вопрос пользы никому не принесёт и, тем самым, должен быть предан забвению. А ответ: т.к. в объявлении цикла переменной присвоили новое значение.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Так задача и состоит в том, чтобы помочь именно ТС, а не вам.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, я всегда думал, что мы не ТС помогаем, а базу данных составляем) Но спорить не буду на сей счёт - мы друг друга всё равно не переубедим, думаю)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб так вот для чего оказывается этот сайт

Comment: @Etki  на самом деле политика ресурса такова, что воросы, которые не будут полезны в дальнейшем хоть кому-то, здесь не приветствуются. Это никак не  персональные он-лайн консультации для тех, кто не умеет или не хочет читать литературу. Насчет конкретно этого вопроса я не уверен, что он совсем бесполезен, хоть автор и не приложил минимальнейших усилий для его решения.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow задача помочь исключительно ТС здесь как бы на последнем месте - здесь не персональная бесплатная консультация, вопрос и ответ должны быть полезны, в первую очередь, сообществу. Дело здесь дошло до того, что авторам не принадлежат ни вопросы ни ответы, любой участник, поощряемый сообществом, может как угодно изменять их в целях сообщества, а не ТС.

Comment: @pavlofff я уже раза четыре взорвался, пока участвовал в этих дискуссиях. Хоть убей не помню политики ресурса, которая подразумевала вычищение всего, что не угодило божественному взору.

Comment: @pavlofff Автор вопроса не может отвечать за вас и за целое сообщество. Он задает тот вопрос, который именно его лично волнует, а не вас.  Вы можете задать свой вопрос. Этот форум как раз и есть "персональная бесплатная консультация", как, впрочем, и остальные форумы по программированию.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Автор может и не задумываться, будет ли его вопрос полезен сообществу - сообщество задумается, нужен ли этот вопрос ресурсу. 1 - это не форум, а Q&A. 2 - Автор ДОЛЖЕН отвечать за сообщество и следовать его правилам, так как является его частью (как минимум ознакомится со Справкой) 3 - Автор может задавать все что угодно, но не все из того, что задают - остается на ресурсе. На форуме, да - в основном персональное общение, здесь (в идеале) вопрос должен быть полезен кому то еще, кроме самого автора. Идея в том, чтобы не тратить время на поиск решения, а использовать готовое.

Comment: @pavlofff Автор вопроса ни вам, ни мне, ни тем более мифическому сообществу ничего не должен. Он задает те вопросы, которые его волнуют. Он - не телепат и не может знать, что именно вам будет полезно. И это вообще не его проблема. Каждый сам для себя находит то, что ему полезно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому, что вот здесь `for(x = 5;x<5;x++){}` присваивается х число 5. И следовательно ответ  `х=5`.

Answer (score 3):

В этом `for` предложении

```
for(x = 5;x<5;x++){}
    ^^^^^
```

вы явно присвоили значение 5 статическому члену класса `x`.

Это значение и выводится в следующей строке:

```
System.out.println(x);
```

Предложение `for` выполняется следующим образом. Сначала вычисляется его первая часть инициализации `x = 5;`, а лишь затем проверяется условие `x < 5;`

Так как условие будет равно `false`, то ни одной итерации цикла не выполнится. Тем не менее члену класса `x` уже будет присвоено новое значение.